# Why I can't get the Attribute name using this method?

Tags: java, xml

```
@Test
public void testDolaAmeng() throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dy = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dy.newDocumentBuilder();

    File f = new File("E:/JavaApps/day02/src/_05XML/connect.xml");

    Document dc = db.parse(f);

    NodeList nl = dc.getElementsByTagName("linkman");

    Element et = (Element) nl.item(1);

    String name1 = et.getAttribute("name");

    System.out.println(name1);  //nothing  get.....

    // Element son1  =(Element)et.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);

    //String name2 = son1.getTextContent();

    //System.out.println(name2)  //      using this can get huing
}
```

This is my XML file, I can't get the name using the first print . I don't know why
  in  name2 I can get the ihuing  ,in name1  however  the answer is nothing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2hmY.png)

Comment: Don't post images of your XML. Post the XML itself, as code-formatted text.

Comment: The only attributes that exist in this XML are `id="1"` and `id="2"`.

Comment: ...sorry,I don't know how to put the XML it can't let me put //./.

Comment: The same way you add your code. You paste it, then select it and press Ctrl-K (or the icon button "Code Sample".

Comment: Can't be the linkman 's name???   ...

Comment: No. name is an **element**, not an attribute. That's why, to get the linkman **elements**, you called `getElementsByTagName()`. Not `getAttributesByTagName()`.

Comment: Thanks,i Iwil think about it carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is not an attribute, it's a child element. You can do the following if you know there is always one descendant (not only child!) with that name, which your schema suggests:

```
String nameValue = et.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
```

To clarify notation

```
<linkman id="5"> // linkman - element, id - attribute
    <name>Will</name> // element, child of linkman element
    <something> // element, child of linkman element, parent of nestedSomething, ancestor of nestedSomething text node
        <nestedSomething> // element, child of something, descendant of linkman
            blablabla
        </nestedSomething>
    </something>
</linkman>
```

All children are descendants, all parents are ancestors.

Comment: @listephen: you're welcome, I know how frustrating not knowing the names for things can be.